# Is it possible to edit Whatsapp contact names without giving the app my contact access?

Tags: ios

I am not a super fan of Whatsapp and only have a few contacts. But recently, due to some reasons, I need to talk to more than 20 people on Whatsapp.

The problem is, I do not want to grant Whatsapp access to my contacts (iOS). And in the app, all contacts are displayed as mobile numbers, instead of names.

Is there any way that I can edit their names (so that I can remember them) without giving the contact permission to the Whatsapp App?

Thanks!

Comment: Does https://faq.whatsapp.com/5472030609512325/?cms_platform=iphone&helpref=platform_switcher help?

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you edit the question to explain which steps you took, what the result was and where the result started to differ from expectations?

Comment: Your contacts are only visible to you and to Whatsapp not to others

Comment: If I grant WhatsApp access to my contacts, does it send a notification to all of them stating "XXX (my name) has joined WhatsApp"? This is a feature I've noticed other applications, such as Telegram, do not possess. @Ruskes

Answer (score -1):

If you have got a PC/Mac that’s simple download bluestacks emulator or any other and install whatsapp on it(with new number account) and then add the contacts/modify that will appear in your whatsapp. However beware i’m not sure if whatsapp supports multidevice feature as telegram does so backup your data as logging in other device may log you out the current device. Then add that whatsapp web to your iphone/ipad to acces that account with the emulator contact list. And you may use the app version in your phone for your primary account . Hope this helps

Comment: This may require some more detailed steps, download links and assurance it actually works to be useful.